# What 3D function could describe this shape

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, 3d

I need to find the function f(x,y) which could describe the surface below. Could you help me?

[image: click]

Comment: I think you want a function $z = f(x,y)$. It might help if you provide a source for the image.

Comment: It's impossible to give an exact answer from a visual inspection. How was the graph generated? Solution to some differential equation? Interpolation from data? If I had to guess from the image it looks like the product of a cubic in the bottom right variable and a quartic in the bottom left variable, but that's just a visual inspection on the smoothness and number of turning points and simplifying to a "nice" case (most polynomials in 2d don't split nicely into two polynomials in 1d)

Comment: You are right Ethan, it should be f(x,y). I edited my question. Of course, I need only a general and exemplary form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting constants in:

$$ z= y\, x^2 (x^2 - 1) , (-1< x <1),\,  (-1< y <1 )    $$

Comment: You can find more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point).

Comment: Not quite;  the function is  even  in $x$, but odd in $y$...

Comment: So you missed the link to the [monkey saddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_saddle).